# How to statically link Qt5 with CMake in CLion?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cmake, qt5

I downloaded the sources of Qt and compiled it with `-static` flag into `/usr/local/Qt5_static/`. I created empty project and changed `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Splines)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -static -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -v")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(Qt5_DIR "/usr/local/Qt5_static/")
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

add_executable(Splines ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Splines Qt5::Widgets)
```

There is a linker error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.7.0'
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looks like linker tried to link shared lib instead of static lib i compiled. I tried other variations of CMakeLists.txt but failed.

How to statically link Qt with cmake properly? 
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are **compiler flags**, but `target_link_libraries` uses **linker flags**, which are `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`. For static link you need to add `-static` to *linker flags*.